# LNK1124 error debugger cannot find .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, solution

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJuwY.png)

I'm having an error with visual studio every time I'm trying to use cin to get the guess of the user without that it works fine.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuoHF.png)

[console message with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSD4e.png)

Comment: If you think this can help other users then please post the question in a proper manner and then post answer on your own.

Comment: thank you for telling me i'm new here

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [ask] and reworking the question to meet the site rules. Do not use images where text will do. For one thing, I can't compile and test a png file and doubt few others can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happening to me since I install visual studio 2017 just a couple of days ago.

I'm trying to learn c++ for unreal engine just started learning and i came across
that error anyone who have this error maybe this can be helpful for them.

first, let me tell you wah t the problem was i was trying to run a 32bit debugger on my 64bit pc cause visual studio install it that way so if you are getting this error on any of your projects all you have to do is change the project to an x64 bit project.

go to the Top bar  "Build"
then go to "Configuration manager"
in there change it to x64 bit instead of 32bit

hopefully this can help someone

the link to the page that i read to fix is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-configure-visual-cpp-projects-to-target-64-bit-platforms).

after all the changes code runs well and no error anymore.

Comment: Glad to know that this issue has been resolved, if so, please mark your solution as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day:)